# Indexing items in figure captions

Tags: captions, indexing

I want to include items given in figure captions in my index, but LaTeX treats those differently, perhaps related to a list of figures (that I am not employing), and they appear as a separate alphabetical block in the index. I have seen ways to address this for citations in figure captions, but not index items, per se. Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please add an example that produce this problem?

Comment: Is there any news on this?