# How to include an \index item within a figure \caption

Tags: captions, indexing

I would like to create an \index{} item specified within a figure \caption, as posted in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318578/indexing-items-in-figure-captions), which was closed because it did not contain a minimum example.

Here is code that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}  

Text here.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{myCat.eps}
\caption{Here is a picture of a cat.\index{cat}} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
! Argument of \@iiminipage has an extra }.
<inserted text>
            \par
l.50 \end{figure}
```

I'm using TeXShop v. 3.96 under MacOS 10.12.6.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all that matters is what page `\index` is on.  It doesn't have to be IN the `\caption` as long as it is in the figure environment.  Unless you WANT to include the list of figures in the index page listing.

Answer (score 3):

`\protect` will solve the error, and the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}  

Text here.

\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics{myCat.eps}
\caption{Here is a picture of a cat.\protect\index{cat}} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First time I've used `tufte-book` and found that it's not only the layout that differs from `book` but also some of the commands.

In the `book` class `\caption{Some catty text\index{cat}}` works fine. However if an index is being created then there will be an entry for the LoF page as well as the figure page. The `book` solution to this is `\caption[For the LoF]{Some catty text\index{cat}}` so the index entry does not appear in the LoF.

In `tufte-book` you have to `\protect` the caption's index entry:

```
\caption[For the LoF]{Some catty text\protect{cat}}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, some of the commands that work fine in `book` fail in `tufte-book`.  The most annoying failure of the verso-recto placement of figures.  (I have to go through entire chapters and hand code \forceversofloat !)  I hadn't noticed the indexing in the List of Figures... thanks so much for that information!  (+1).